# Why should we use xsd over c# classes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

In our project, we are having xsd schema files, we are auto generating c# classes for xsd and using them. Each time, if we need to do modification, we are asked to do it in xsd file and which later generated into c# code.

My question is, why we need xsd in first place, why can't we directly have the serializable c# classes created.

Comment: Are you asking us to guess why your teacher requires you to use xsd files in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the changes to the classes are a result of changes to some XML data structure that the app supports.  With that assumption, here are a couple of reasons to keep the XSDs in sync:

1. If you ever re-generated the class files from the XSDs all changes to the classes would be lost
2. The XSDs could be used to validate any XML document that could be (de)serialized using those classes.

Comment: @D Stanley, If i version control the generated classes at this point and remove the xsd. (There will not be any code generation hereafter from xsd). Any modification here after I'll do it only to the c# classes, then what are the disadvantages I would have?

Comment: @PrinceAshitaka You're basically asking "what are the advantages of having an XSD?" which is easily answered by looking at general reference material on using schemas.  You then need to ask yourself if those benefits are worth the effort in maintaining it (we can't really answer that for you).

Comment: @Servy, thanks I got some pointers from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140355/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-xml-schemas thanks again!!